# Does adding a value to list in Java copy the data or create a reference?

Tags: java, list

I have two lists:

```
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

List<List<Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

I add a few numbers to my list l1 using `l1.add()`.

I then add the list l1 to second list l2 (which is now a list of Arraylist) using `l2.add(index, l1)`.

I then clear l1 as I want to do other computation and create the list which will again be added to l2. Clearing is done using `l1.clear()`.
On clearing l1, I notice l2 is also cleared.
Does `l2.add()` create only a reference to l1 ?

Comment: If you add an object to a collection in Java, and then modify the object, either taken from the collection or using the original reference, it should change everywhere.  So, a copy is not made AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, it only adds a reference, as your experience indicates.

Answer (score 2):

for objects like `ArrayList` and etc, when you pass them to function (like `add` here), You pass a copy of their address, so function can work or save that address (like `add` here which save it in second list) so any change on that object like `clear` will reflect on second list, except if you create a new list and assign it to your first list (now it references to another address) but your second list has address of your last list and work on that.
 for example:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(list1); // list2 contains reference to where list1 points, not to list1 itself.
                  // so any change on where list1 points, happen for list2 reference too.
list1.add(1); // happen for list2
list1 = new ArrayList<>(); // doesn't happen for list2 because I change the address
                           // saved in list1 but list2 contains last address and work with last address
list1.add(5);
System.out.println(list2.get(0).get(0)); // print 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes in Java it use the reference of particular objects that have added to list.

For Example:

Let **l1** and **l2** two list.

Now,

```
String a="Some String";
l1.add(a);
l2.add(l1);
```

It means **l1** have **a** at index 0. 
and **l2** have **l1** at index 0.

case 1:
if we need to get value of a from **L1** then it is like,

```
l1.get(0);
```

same as for **l2** is like,

```
l2.get(0).get(0);
```

now your Answer :

```
l1.clear();
```

clear all elements of **l1**.
so how will you access the value of **a** after clearing **l1** because it doesn't exist.

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    String a = "some value";
    l1.add(a);
    l2.add(l1);
    System.out.println("l1 Size : " + l1.size());
    System.out.println("l2 Size : " + l2.size());
    l1.clear();
    System.out.println("l1 updated Size : " + l1.size());
    System.out.println("l2 updated Size : " + l2.size());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
l1 Size : 1
l2 Size : 1
l1 updated Size : 0
l2 updated Size : 1
```